# Directory-tree listing with status in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python script which shows a list of all files (and directories) in a given directory, but I can't understand why "Status" not working and to all files print the same data (such as size, creation time, etc..)

How can it be fixed?

```
import os

rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    status = os.stat(rootDir)
    print('Mapes ceļš: %s' % dirName)
   
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t Objekts:  ' '%s'  % fname, status)
```

Comment: You define `status` once on the `rootDir` and then don't change it. So it keeps printing the same thing. You'd need to define the path to the file and change your line `print('\t Objekts:  ' '%s'  % fname, status)` to something **along the lines** of `print('\t Objekts:  ' '%s'  % fname, os.stat(path+fname))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggested solution, unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

If I create the following code 
`
import os
rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    status = os.stat(rootDir)
    print('Mapes ceļš: %s' % dirName)
    
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t Objekts:  ' '%s'  % fname, os.stat(rootDir + fname))
`
The following error is displayed 
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '.9.py' 

9.py is this script file name.